# if else regex replace all

Tags: java, regex

Given a string like that:

```
"CSV;XML;ZIP"
```

I'm trying to make a regex to transform it to something like that:

```
".csv,.xml,.zip"
```

I tried this regex pattern : `([^;]*)(;|$)` replace with: `.\L$1,`

but the result is : .csv,.xml,.zip,.,

I need my regex to satisfy :

1. "CSV" -> ".csv"
2. "CSV;XML;ZIP" -> ".csv,.xml,.zip"

I feel like I need to add something inside my regex which says: if it is the end of the string don't add ',' else do, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Case modifying operators are not supported in the replacement patterns in Java `replace` regex methods. If you are not "married" to regex, 1) lowercase the input, 2) split with `;` and 3) join with `,.` and append `.` at the start.

Comment: Try using StringJoiner. Example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Comment: BTW, regarding *I feel like I need to add somthing inside my regex wich says : if it is the end of the string don't add ',' else do, but I don't know how to do it.* - you just need `+`, not `*`. `([^;]+)(;|$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you okey, I thought regex was the "cleanest" way to do that, but if it is not I'll use  string join soluiton, BTW your solution ([^;]+)(;|$) gives -> .csv,.xml,.zip, so there is a "," at the end and it shouldn't

Comment: Yes, that is why Pshemo mentions you need a conditional replacement, again, this is not supported in Java regex methods. (Conditional replacements are available in Boost and PCRE2)

Comment: My pro tip for regex usage: when you need other people to come with one for your task, then consider that *in your context* regex isnt the answer. Why use a regex to change casing, when a simple `toLowerCase()` on your input string is guaranteed to give you what want for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To generate dynamic replacement you can use [`Matcher#replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,​String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)).
- Also you probably want to match *at least one* non-semicolon character for the match, so instead of `([^;]*)` use `([^;]+)`

Demo:

```
String str = "CSV;XML;ZIP";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^;]+)(;|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

String replaced = m.replaceAll(
        match ->
        "." //in all cases replacement will start with dot
        + match.group(1).toLowerCase() //then lowercase ([^;]+)
        + (match.group(2).isEmpty() ? "" : ",") //then depending on (;|$) we decide if we add comma or not
);
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output: `.csv,.xml,.zip`

Comment: A good example why regexes are sometimes just the wrong approach. "Look here, I have a screw, so lets use a hammer to force it into the wall". Yeah, sure, works. But is it what you *should* be doing?!

Comment: @GhostCat yeah i agree, but at the begining i thought that it is a  really simple regex that anyone who has decent knowlege of regex could easly do, and (also it's my own junior dev opinion) if you could do it with one shot regex than do it with regex because it will be more efficient than a loop, but in this case it turned out that it is impossible to do it with a one shot  regex so i agree that the best solution would be the one with string.split.join

Answer (score 4):

-- This is just another way to do it, that you can think about...

Like someone else already menitoned, in this case, you should think about going trough it with a loop. Split the Input by semicolon and process through it..

I'm using the Stream API in my solution

1. lowercase the string
2. Split the string by semicolon and create a stream out of the substrings
3. Map toLowerCase
4. Map ("." + element)
5. Collect with StringJoiner - use comma as seperator

```java
        String input = "CSV;ZIP;XML";
        String output = Arrays.stream(input.toLowerCase().split(";"))
                .map(s -> "." + s)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

This solution works and in my opinion is much more readable than a regex

Comment: Thats a good point, i've could just lowerCased the input itself, true

Comment: You are welcome. Note that you only updated your code, not the explanations. Yeah, "comments lie", all the time ;-)